# TCP/IP constantly receiving data

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, camera, client

I have a problem when communicating with the SICK camera via TCP / IP. Camera (server) and application in Python (client). Data is received only once when my program is turned on. Could you tell me how to change to continuous data reception? Not only one TCP/IP frame.

```
import socket

HOST = '192.168.3.14'    #server IP
PORT = 8999              #port
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024       #max size of data

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST,PORT))
    data=s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

print (data)
```

Comment: use a `while` loop...?

Comment: I am not experienced programmer. Could you explain: while loop with what condition?

Comment: Sorry, that's a bit too basic for SO, you're better off finding a tutorial...

Comment: I know how while loop works but I have got problem how implemented it in this case..

Comment: `while True:`, receive data.  If no data, break from loop.  print data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [receiving data over a python socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289035/receiving-data-over-a-python-socket)